# How to download image from url and display in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, download, temporary-files

I am trying to download an image and displaying it in a view in rails.

The reason why I want to download it is because the url contains some api-keys which I am not very fond of giving away.

The solution I have tried thus far is the following:

```
#Model.rb file
def getUrlMethod
   someUrlToAPNGfile = "whatever.png"
   file = Tempfile.new(['imageprependname', '.png'], :encoding => "ascii-8bit")
   file.write(open(data).read)
   return "#{Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host]}#{file.path}"
end
#This seems to be downloading the image just fine. However the url that is returned does not point to a legal place
```

Under development I get this URL for the picture: `localhost:3000/var/folders/18/94qgts592sq_yq45fnthpzxh0000gn/T/imageprependname20130827-97433-10esqxh.png`

That image link does not point anywhere useful.

My theories to what might be wrong is:

1. The tempfile is deleted before the user can request it
2. The url points to the wrong place
3. The url is not a legal route in the routes file

A am currently not aware of any way to fix either of these. Any help?

---

By the way: I do not need to store the picture after I have displayed it, as it will be changing constantly from the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two options:

First, embed the image directly in the HTML documents, see
http://www.techerator.com/2011/12/how-to-embed-images-directly-into-your-html/
http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter

Second, in the HTML documents, write the image tag as usual:

```
<img src="/remote_images/show/whatever.png" alt="whatever" />
```

Then you create a `RemoteImages` controller to process the requests for images. In the action `show`, the images will be downloaded and returned with [send_data](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_data).

You don't have to manage temporary files with both of these options.

Comment: That first link really solved it for me. I have some backbone that blocks me from doing Brad Werth's method.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the file anywhere in the public folder of the rails application. The right path would be something like this `#{Rails.root}/public/myimages/<image_name>.png`  and then you can refer to it with a URL like this `http://localhost:3000/myimages/<image_name>.png`. Hope this will help.

Comment: I don't want to save the file, as it will only be used ones (in the worst case).